# Mongo Querying of Database with 1 document taking too long

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose, querying

App: Nodejs Express app and using Mongoose for Mongo Database

I have a Collection which is config and I query it like this:

```
Collection.findOne().lean().exec((err, config => {});
```

However, on my server for a particular request this being called 90ish times takes over 10 seconds in total. Out of the 90ish, I can see most of the queries are in milliseconds and some are in 1-2 seconds.

What would be taking so long to query this when it just has one document? Also is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: Maybe maxing out a connection pool and some queries have to wait for a connection to free up?

Comment: Can you please provide the surrounding code for reference? If you're calling this in a loop, you might want to do an `$in` query and only make 1 database request instead. I can elaborate in an answer provided more context.

Comment: You can Probably try using indexes in mongodb and then check the query execution time,Where as regarding to the connections which are called multiple time try to use $in query and make one database request.